# Move the page links position on single post

Tags: css, wordpress

I use WordPress.

And I adding this code to make multi page post on single post.

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

But the page links display after related post box. Tell me how to change positon the page links box after content. For related post I used Jetpack plugin.

Comment: You haven't included enough details to allow us to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. And this for image. https://prnt.sc/pa3wbi in image pages links position after related post. And I want to move the pages links number position before like button or after the content.

Comment: Send us a link to your post please.

Comment: Sorry. This is link my post page http://www.keepburger.com/2019/08/18/resep-dan-cara-membuat-rempeyek-kacang-tanah-renyah/ you see the links pages position after related post, and i want move after conten or before like button.

Answer (score 0):

Helllo,

Add this to your theme's Custom CSS:

```
.single .entry-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.hentry #jp-relatedposts {
  order: 3;
}

.entry-content .page-links {
  order: 1;
}

#content div.sharedaddy,
#main div.sharedaddy,
div.sharedaddy {
  order: 2;
}
```